# Pad row with default if values not found PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to return the last 7 days of user_activity, but for those empty days I want to add 0 as value

Say I have this table

```
actions |  id   | date
------------------------
67      |  123  | 2019-07-7
90      |  123  | 2019-07-9
100     |  123  | 2019-07-10
50      |  123  | 2019-07-13
30      |  123  | 2019-07-15
```

and this should be the expected output , for the last 7 days

```
  actions |  id   | date
    ------------------------
    90      |  123  | 2019-07-9
    100     |  123  | 2019-07-10
    0       |  123  | 2019-07-11  <--- padded
    0       |  123  | 2019-07-12  <--- padded
    50      |  123  | 2019-07-13
    0       |  123  | 2019-07-14  <--- padded
    30      |  123  | 2019-07-15
```

Here is my query so far, I can only get the last 7 days
but not sure if it's positive to add to default values

```
SELECT *
FROM user_activity
WHERE action_day > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days' 
ORDER BY uid, action_day
```

Comment: Is id always 123?  If not, how should this be calculated?

Comment: @Jeremy its the activity of a single user, so not necessarily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may left join your table with `generate_series`. First you need to have a way to use the rows for distinct ids. That set can then be correctly joined with the main table.

```
WITH days
AS (SELECT id,dt
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM user_activity
        ) AS ids
  CROSS JOIN generate_series(
        CURRENT_DATE - interval '7 days', 
    CURRENT_DATE,  interval '1 day') AS dt
    )
SELECT  
     coalesce(u.actions,0)
    ,d.id
    ,d.dt
FROM days d LEFT JOIN user_activity u ON u.id = d.id AND u.action_day = d.dt
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5359e9cda2493ea5f16e6a2550fbcfbc)

Comment: +1.  You beat me to it by 1 minute.  BTW You do not need to coalesce id or dt - you can take them direct from days.  Also the where clause is redundant as there are only 7 days in the cte.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock : You're right, I've modified it now.

Comment: impressive! thank you very much! I appreciate it guys